# Ensuring random order for iteration over Set Python

Tags: python, set, iteration

I am iterating over a Set in Python. In my application I prefer that the iteration be in a random order each time. However what I see is that I get the same order each time I run the program. This isn't fatal but is there a way to ensure randomized iteration over a Set?

Comment: I think you have to convert it to `list` .  `s=set([1,2,3,4]); print random.choice(list(s))`

Comment: The easiest way to get those results is to turn it into a `list` and randomize that. I'd recommend doing it that way unless you're running into performance issues and can't afford creating the new `list`.

Comment: related (not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`random.shuffle`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle) on a list of the set.

```
>>> import random
>>> s = set('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
>>> for i in range(5): #5 tries
    l = list(s)
    random.shuffle(l)
    print ''.join(l) #iteration


nguoqbiwjvelmxdyazptcfhsrk
fxmaupvhboclkyqrgdzinjestw
bojweuczdfnqykpxhmgvsairtl
wnckxfogjzpdlqtvishmeuabry
frhjwbipnmdtzsqcaguylkxove
```

Comment: You can also just do `print(''.join(random.sample(s, len(s))))`.

Comment: Thanks @Brien, that's just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use random.shuffle to shuffle your set:

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>> a = set([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> b = list(a)
>>> shuffle(b)
>>> b
[4, 2, 1, 3, 5]
>>>
```