# Creating a random number with the usage of set()

Tags: python, random

Considering the fact that set is an unordered data structure, I began to wonder if it is possible to create a truly "random" number with the usage of it (or with the usage of a dictionary).

Lets consider such an input number represented as a string:

```
input = "0123456789"
```

And then we convert the string into a set:

```
input_set = set(input)
```

After printing the result of this operation multiple times, we have following example outputs:

> {'9', '3', '4', '6', '0', '7', '1', '8', '5', '2'}
>
> {'3', '4', '2', '1', '5', '7', '0', '8', '6', '9'}

Now we can convert the elements of the set into a string with the usage of:

```
output = ''.join(set_input)
```

And the result of this operation for the sets above would be:

> 9346071852
>
> 3421570869

Would generation of a random number in a following way be considered a good practice?

And most of all, do I understand correctly that it would be a "pseudorandom" number, because we could reproduce the result with the usage of some seed value or key?

Comment: `set` is not random at *all*; it's *arbitrary*. The language makes no guarantees about any property of the output. An implementation would be free to sort the elements if it so chose.

Comment: @chepner so why does it denerate a different output on every run?

Comment: Just because it is different doesn't mean it is random. Plus, it's different in the interpreter *you* are using; that doesn't mean *every* interpreter has to do so.

Comment: I just tried this 10000 times in a loop. I got exactly **1** different outputs. So much for randomness...

Comment: @GalAbra: [Why is the order in dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](//stackoverflow.com/q/15479928)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Ensuring random order for iteration over Set Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598562/ensuring-random-order-for-iteration-over-set-python)

Comment: Also, see https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONHASHSEED.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not good practice.

The order is determined by the random hash seed, and this seed is **fixed for the current Python interpreter**. You would not be able to produce more than one 'random' order per interpreter. The hash seed is also a *implementation detail*, there to prevent a class of denial of service attacks. Different Python implementations (including future releases produced by Python.org) are free to come up with a different implementation of sets that doesn't use a hash seed. See the [`-R` switch documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-r) for more details.

The seed is also aimed at producing good hashing performance, not cryptographic security. The ordering of values in a set is also determined by the insertion order of the elements; it is a combination of the hash for each value and any clashes when translating the hash into the (limited) choices of slots available in a hash table that determines the ordering of the elements. If you were to repeat your experiments, you'd almost certainly see a bias towards certain numbers appearing in certain positions.

Stick to the [`secrets` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/secrets.html) to produce cryptographically secure random numbers.

For non-secure operations, just use the `random` module; using `random.shuffle()` on your digits would already give a far better distribution of the numbers, statistically speaking.